# Ball in a spinning disc

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

So imagine we have a disc at rest and a ball at the middle of its radius. Now the disc starts rotating with constant angular velocity. Where will the ball go? Will it remain at $R/2$?

[Watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LDxOSz80pI)

Comment: If there's no friction then it will remain at R/2. To find out what happens otherwise, draw free-body diagram.

Comment: the ball can rotate with the disc if it gets a centripetal force-otherwise it will move radially outward for an observer on the disc